# Where are the spare fuses on a 2014 model Suzuki Alto?

Tags: suzuki, fuse-panel

I am currently installing a hardwire kit for a 2014 model Suzuki Alto. I am having a rather elemental problem at the minute in that there doesn't appear to be a fuse puller or any spare fuses in either the engine compartment fuse box or the dashboard fuse box. The manual informs me that I must ensure that the spare fuses remain with the vehicle but doesn't specify where they are kept.

Does anyone know where they might be hiding? Is there a tertiary fuse box in altos anywhere?

Here are the diagrams from the manual and a (slightly oblique) photo of the internal fuses where I would expect the spares to be kept:

[image: suzuki Alto manual page on fuses 1]

[image: Suzuki Alto manual page on fuses 2]

[image: Suzuki Alto internal fuse box]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So rather embarrassingly it turns out I was missing the obvious all along. The spares and fuse extractor are contained within the lid of the engine fuse box. Undo the clips on both sides, take off the lid and flip it over:

[image: spare fuse location Suzuki Alto 2014 onwards]

The fuse puller is narrower than the ones you can buy at Halfords, which do not work with the shape of the fuse box on the new Altos.

Answer (score 4):

The fuse puller is in the centre of the fuse panel toward the right, lined up with between the 6th and 8th fuses.  The spare fuse I believe is in the fifth fuse slot, labelled in the below image as #3.

[image: Alto Fuse Box]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately this doesn't seem to match up with the arrangement that I have on my model - I have added some pictures to show what I have :)